# DOSBOX não reconhece alguns comandos de script batch, como resolver?

Tags: windows, cmd, batch, bat, ms-dos

Estava fazendo um script simples em `batch`e testando com o CMD do Windows 10, e este rodou normalmente. Porém, ao tentar rodar o mesmo script com o DOSBOX, o sistema deu erro no uso do `GOTO`, rendendo os seguintes erros:

- Illegal command: Title:.
- Illegal command: cls&goto

O trecho que é aplicado se assemelha a isso:

```
:menu
Title: Programa
echo.
echo Meu programa
echo.
echo .

set /p op=Digite aqui a operação desejada: 

if %opcao%==1 (cls&goto menu)
```

Todos os outros scripts simples que eu fiz rodavam também em DOSBOX sem problema algum, eu posso resolver esses problemas para rodar os scripts também em emuladores de DOS ou em dispositivos com o DOS original?

Comment: `Title: Programa` não funcionou no Win10, ficou : no titulo ao invés de programa, creio que deveria ser apenas `Title Programa` e tente separar o `cls&goto` para (`cls & goto`) ... estou enferrujado, quanto a sintaxe (tenho DOSbox em casa, depois testarei)

Comment: Os CLS&GOTO pararam de dar problema, mas o title ainda não é reconhecido como um comando válido

Comment: Acredito que o comando title não exista no DOS, você precisa levar em conta que o `COMMAND.COM` e o `cmd.exe` não interpretam arquivos bat exatamente da mesma forma, e o comando title é algo que só faz sentido no Windows, no DOS não existe uma janela para você definir o titulo

Comment: Sendo o caso de não existir você pode então suprimir ou simplesmente não setar o titulo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** O **`Title`** não é um comando interno ou externo do **MS-DOS**, e nem do **DOSBox**

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

---

**2.** O DOSBox se propõe a emular em “software”, o ambiente do sistema operacional de disco e os equipamentos físicos necessários, isso para dar suporte a execução de jogos antigos, feitos para os processadores 286/386 e outros dessa geração, que são compatíveis com o sistema operacional MS-DOS.

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> ***O DOSBox é um emulador do DOS que usa a biblioteca SDL, o que torna o DOSBox muito***
> ***fácil de portar para diferentes plataformas. O DOSBox já foi portado para muitas***
> ***plataformas diferentes, como Windows, BeOS, Linux, MacOS X...***
>
> ***O DOSBox também emula CPU: 286/386 realmode/modo protegido, Directory***
> ***FileSystem/XMS/EMS, gráficos andy/Hercules/CGA/EGA/VGA/VESA, uma placa de som***
> ***SoundBlaster / Gravis Ultra para excelente compatibilidade de som com jogos mais antigos...***
>
> ***Você pode "reviver" os bons velhos tempos com a ajuda do DOSBox, ele pode***
> ***rodar muitos dos clássicos antigos que não rodam no seu novo computador!***

---

---

**3.** Perceba que o projeto DOSBox não se propõe a oferecer o "Sistema Operacional de Disco" (**MS-DOS**), ou lhe dar acesso às execuções de todos os comandos **internos/externos*** desse sistema operacional, o que ele visa é apenas emular do sistema até o hardware necessário (vide lista abaixo), para a suporte a execução de jogos antigos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

---

**4.** Para obter todos os comandos do DOSBox, use:

```
help /all
```

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

---

**5.** Para saber o que é possível personalizar no DOSBox e também conhecer todas as opções de configurações, consulte o **[DOSBoxManual](https://www.dosbox.com/DOSBoxManual.html)**, onde vai perceber que atribuir